# How to divide data into columns using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

My goal is to create an overview of completed games throughout the year using thymeleaf.

I've tried using table, but i can only insert data into rows, but my goal is to look something like this:

Jan    | Feb | Mar
Tetris  | /   | Diablo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please put some code or maybe a sketch of what you want to show.